# PHP->Python JSON issue

Tags: php, python, json, python-3.x

What am I doing wrong? Python3:

```
>>> import json
>>> s = "\"{'key': 'value'}\""
>>> obj = json.loads(s)
>>> obj['key']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Given JSON string is produced by `json_encode()` from php

> Real string:
>   `{sessionid:5,file:\/home\/lol\/folder\/folder\/file.ttt}`.

**UPDATE**: Problem is because i transfer json string as command line to `shell_exec` in php, and read it using `sys.argv[1]`... So quotes are removed by shell.

PHP Code (which runs python script with `shell_exec`)

```
$arg = json_encode(['sessionid' => $session->getId(), 'file' => $filename]);
shell_exec('python3 script.py ' . $arg);
```

Python code:

```
import json, sys
s = json.loads(sys.argv[1]) #fails already
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kasra answer is correct, `ast` does the trick, but, additionally i had to 'fix' my string with php - to prevent 'damaging' (by shell?):

php code:

```
$cmd = json_encode(['sessionid' => $session->getId(), 'file' => $filename]);
$cmd = str_replace('"', '\'', $cmd);
$cmd = str_replace('\\/', '/', $cmd);
$cmd = 'python3 program.py "' . $cmd . '"';
exec($cmd);
```

python code:

```
import json, sys, ast  
task = json.loads("\"" + sys.argv[1] + "\"")
task = ast.literal_eval(task)

sessionid = task['sessionid'] # DONE!:)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at this JSON:

```
"\"{'key': 'value'}\""
```

You have a string containing an escaped quote, followed by a dictionary-like object, then an escaped quote.  When you try to decode this you wind up with the following:

```
"{'key': 'value'}"
```

That's a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: Without this, `json.loads` raises `ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
`

Comment: Because the inner string is not JSON. JSON always has double quotes around keys and values.

Comment: Yep! And such JSON string is produced by `json_encode()` from php

Comment: I would look at your object before it's been serialized in PHP then.  You need those quotes to be double, or it isn't valid syntax.

Comment: PHP: `json_encode(['sessionid' => $session->getId(), 'file' => $filename])` -- python script receives this as a command line argument with `shell_exec()`

Comment: What I mean is, if your PHP function is giving out JSON formatted like that, you need to look there for a solution.  Otherwise, you'll need to replace the single quotes with double quotes once you get the response in Python.  Alternatively, you could use the solution given by @Kasra, but I would be more interested in fixing the problem than working around it.

Comment: I'm not much with PHP, but I know that strings can be defined with both single and double quotes with slightly different effects (single quotes are more "literal").  If the object you are serializing from PHP is defined such that you have single quotes, perhaps those single quotes are being preserved in the final JSON string.  The PHP you posted does use single quotes for `'sessionid'` and `'file'`.  What happens if you change them to double quotes?

Comment: @paidhima i've changed most of strings in php code to be in double quotes, anything is same (i mean string which comes to python script).

Comment: You can't make Python take invalidly formatted JSON as valid JSON.  You can either figure out why you're getting the output you are from PHP or use Kasra's answer below to bypass the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As your string surrounded by 2 quote that you escaped one of them so after reading the string with `json` the result will be string,So after that you can use `ast.literal_eval` to convert your string to dictionary :

```
>>> obj = json.loads(s)
>>> obj
"{'key': 'value'}"
>>> import ast
>>> new=ast.literal_eval(obj)
>>> new['key']
'value'
```